# gcc 4.9.1 not standard compliant? (std::runtime_error)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc4.9

We would like to have a own definition of `std::runtime_error:runtime_error(const string& arg)`. We implement such constructor in terms of the other constructor, i.e., `std::runtime_error:runtime_error(const char*)`, like:

```
namespace std {
  runtime_error::runtime_error(const string& arg)
    : runtime_error(arg.c_str()) {
    ...
  }
}
```

With gcc-4.9.1, this is not possible, since the constructor `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(const string& arg)` does not exist. In *gcc/4.9.1/include/c++/4.9.1/**stdexcept***, we see the following:

```
...
class runtime_error : public exception 
{
  string _M_msg;
  public:
  /** Takes a character string describing the error.  */
  explicit 
  runtime_error(const string& __arg);
  virtual ~runtime_error() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;
  /** Returns a C-style character string describing the general cause of
  *  the current error (the same string passed to the ctor).  */
  virtual const char* 
  what() const _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT;
};
...
```

The standard clearly says that there should be an explicit `runtime_error(const char*)` constructor.

19.2.6 Class runtime_error [runtime.error]

```
namespace std {
class runtime_error : public exception {
public:
explicit runtime_error(const string& what_arg);
explicit runtime_error(const char* what_arg);
};
```

Comment: "*We implement such constructor in terms of the other constructor*" Why would you want to? The one taking a `std::string` has a length built into it, while the other one has to do a `strlen` to compute the length. That's just a pointless waste of time. Also, you're not allowed to rewrite classes in the standard library.

Comment: Are you using `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @FredLarson Should be the default.

Comment: Just try it: doesn't compile (with -std=c++11) until [gcc 4.9.4](https://godbolt.org/g/1ZDBeU), works from [gcc 5.1](https://godbolt.org/g/lhJqpU) and from [clang 3.5](https://godbolt.org/g/OwsZw1)

Comment: @NicolBolas, Not allowed by compiler? I thought all namespaces were "open". Is there something some mechanism using which the compiler closes the namespaces (like packages in Java)?

Comment: @blackpen Unless specified it is UB to add anything to the `std` namespace.

Comment: @blackpen Not allowed by the C++ standard because `namespace std` (and, as of C++17, `namespace std[someNumber]`) are special.

Comment: @BaummitAugen, Got you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ c++11 is not on by default in 4.9.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Looks like c++98 is the default standard [until 6.1](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx11).

Comment: It seems pointless to argue about standard compliance when the behavior of the entire program is undefined.

Comment: @FredLarson Since one constructor is calling another constructor, C++11 is implied. Constructor delegating is simply not allowed before C++11.

Comment: @T.C. Different types of UB can be more or less safe, right? So, exactly how dangerous is this "undefined behaviour"?

Comment: @BlueDemon: No undefined behaviour is safe per the standard. Implementation defined behaviour does what is specified by a specific implementation, but the behaviour is still outside of the standard itself.

Comment: @rubenvb Appreciate the set theory lesson (!std && gcc = still outside std), but I was more interested in knowing how dangerous this UB is. An elaboration on that would actually be helpful.

Comment: @Blue Undefined behaviour is just that: undefined. In the worst case your program opens a gateway to hell. More likely, your program doesn't do what you think, which is dangerous because you don't immediately see this. Even more likely, your program crashes, but not at the point of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this does not answer your original question, but if the intention really is to intercept the `runtime_error` instantiation, you can do like this (asuming gcc is used):

```
namespace std {
  runtime_error::runtime_error(const string& arg)
  #if (__GNUC__ > 4)
    : runtime_error(arg.c_str())
  #else
    : _M_msg(arg)
  #endif
  {
    // intercept here!
  }
}
```

Hopefully, the invoked `runtime_error(const char*)` will not be implemented in the future in terms of `runtime_error(const string&)`, which would break all your hope and desire. =)